# failed to open stream при попытке загрузить файл

Tags: php, yii

Фреймворк yii2. Мне нудно загрузить несколько изображений. При попытке отправить - ошибка failed to open stream , но сам файл загружается на сервер

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'file');
        foreach ($model->file as $key => $file) {
            $model->image = 'uploads/' . $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension.'**';
            $file->saveAs('uploads/'. $file->baseName . '.' . $file->extension);
        }
        $model->save();

        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

Так как ошибка - записи в БД нету. Если убрать строку с загрузкой на сервер, только оставить запись в БД - работает.
В чем может быть проблема??

> finfo_file(C:\OpenServer\userdata\temp\phpAE1F.tmp): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

$model->save() нужно вызвать перед $file->saveAs(..).

Либо отключить валидацию $model->save(false)

Answer (score 0):

Можно еще вот так - `$model->save(false);`

```
$model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');
        if ($model->file) {
            $model->file->saveAs($model->rus2translit('upload/attachments/' . $model->file->baseName . '.' . $model->file->extension));
            $model->file1 = $model->rus2translit($model->file->baseName . '.' . $model->file->extension);
            $model->save(false);
        }
```